# Text after % is not printing

Tags: c, printf, modulus

I was just completing my assignment when I noticed that the text after the `%` symbol in double quotes is not printing. Here is a very easy example to show this:

```
 //program
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
      printf("remainder of 5%2 is : %d",5%2);//here %2 is not printing
      return 0;
 }
```

output:

```
remainder of 5 is : 1
```

Only the `%2` is not printed by `printf()` rest everything is fine.

Comment: Enable more compiler warnings (e.g.`-Wall`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%%` to print `%`:

```
printf("remainder of 5%%2 is : %d",5%2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ASCII code:

```
printf("remainder of 5%c2 is : %d",37,5%2");
```